# Why do I need another conda environment from tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, conda

I'm currently trying to start working with tensorflow.
I work with anaconda and I tried to install the tensorflow packages in the root environment but it always displays the message: "Several errors encountered".
When I looked it up it says the solution is to create another environment exclusively for tensorflow, I did and it worked. But I'd still like to know what the reason for this is.

Comment: It's probably related to the Tensorflow package version supported by anaconda, I remember coming across similar issues, and solved it by using `pip` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had the same question when I started out. It seemed like it is the "correct" thing to do, so I just did it, but never understood why. After working with TensorFlow for 2 years now, and on multiple machines, I realised just how specific the set of its requirements is. Only a few versions of python are compatible with it, the same thing with `numpy`, and if you want to use NVIDIA GPUs, good luck figuring out the specific versions of `cuda` and `cudnn`.

You don't want to have to tailor most of the python-related software on your machine to running tensorflow. In order to avoid breaking it whenever you install something that requires a higher version of `numpy`, for example, it is best to keep it in a separate environment. This way you have an isolated "container" that keeps everything just the way TensorFlow wants it, while still being able to use other software if needed.
Not to mention that there are several versions of TensorFlow and they all have different requirements.

Comment: still not clear why conda. when you say "how specific the set of its requirements is" - do you mean conda solves this? or conda makes it worse? also there is bunch of virtual environment software they do what you describe in para 2. clarify please how conda is unique in this sense?